# Error in Setting Style Property in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, resourcedictionary

I'm using WPF Toolkit Extended MessageBox ,

base on this page , http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/234113 , I want to Change Ok Property of MessageBox.
my problem is that I can not set TargetType for Style,
I used :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                    xmlns:extToolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended"
                    >

<Style TargetType="{x:Type extToolkit:MessageBox}">
        <Setter Property="OkButtonContent" Value ="[Custom OK]"/>
</Style>
```

it gives me Error in exToolkit:MessagBox , and says Type 'exToolkit:MessageBox' not found.

I added Refrence to Assembly WPFToolkit.Extended  ,  WPFToolkit.Extended.dll but no difference.

When I press ':' after extoolkit it shows other Classes(Types),but does not show MessageBox.

I can Call

```
Microsoft.Windows.Controls.MessageBox.Show("some test");
```

in my project.

Comment: Can you please show the code in the page the references this style. Thanks :)

Comment: Which version of the toolkit are you using? Is it for framework 3.5 or later?

Answer (score 0):

Someone else faced the same problem [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wpf/thread/c84cb379-a0e6-4c06-b94f-b84b9dd78083), though I don't really like the given answer.